# jQuery: how to hide TableTools buttons programmatically

Tags: jquery, datatables, hide, show-hide, tabletools

I am using the latest version of the jQuery plugins DataTables and TableTools (source: https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/).

I have set this up to show two of the standard buttons, one to select all rows and one to deselect all of them. 
So far everything works as intended.

Now I would like to add a simple button to my page to hide these two buttons programmatically. 
**Investigating them in Firebug shows the following:**

```
<div class="DTTT_container">
    <a id="ToolTables_queueTable_0" class="DTTT_button DTTT_button_text" title="select all rows">
        <span>Select All</span>
    </a>
    <a id="ToolTables_queueTable_1" class="DTTT_button DTTT_button_text DTTT_disabled" title="deselect all rows">
        <span>Deselect All</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

**Based on this I tried to hide them both using the class "DTTT_button" and using the unique IDs but in both cases I am unable to do so.**

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function() {
    $('.DTTT_button').hide();
});

$('#myButton').on('click', function() {
    $('#ToolTables_queueTable_0').hide();
    $('#ToolTables_queueTable_1').hide();
});
```

Does anyone know a way to achieve this with a different approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using css property to hide the div

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function() {
    $('#ToolTables_queueTable_0').css("visibility","hidden");
    $('#ToolTables_queueTable_1').css("visibility","hidden");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If your divs have the `visibility` property set, `hide` and `show` doesn't work.

Another thing should be:

> If using !important in your styles, such as  display: none !important,
>   it is necessary to override the style using .css( "display", "block
>   !important") should you wish for .show() to function correctly.

Refer [here](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Try changing the `visibility` or `display` property via jquery

```
$('#ToolTables_queueTable_0').css("visibility","hidden");
```

or

```
$('#ToolTables_queueTable_0').css("display","none");
```

Comment: Careful using `display` during init. I used `display: none` on the 'csv' button while the data was ajax loaded (lest the user save an empty form) then removed it when it was finished, but the button didn't work right, not sure why. Switching to `visibility: hidden` instead did the trick.